# How does wcf implement its authentication?

Tags: wcf, authentication, soap

I've been using wcf for a while and its authentication mechanisms, Windows, UserName/Password, Client certificate for a while.

I'd like to better understand how WCF uses these authentication mechanisms internally when creating SOAP messages and sending them.

Specifically, are the authentication credentials passed by wcf in every SOAP request, or does it only pass the authentication credentials in the first request and then some kind of token is issued and passed back and forth during subsequent sessions?

Are these authentication credentials (username+password, windows, client certificate) passed in a different manner depending on whether the security mode is transport or message? Is it that in message mode, the authentication credentials are inside the SOAP message, while in the transfer mode, http headers are other transport protocol specific are used to pass the authentication credentials?

Lets just assume that the SOAP message is secured using https when Transport mode is used and encrypted when using Message Mode and not worry about message privacy or tampering for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked several big qeustions, but I'll try to answer the question about sessions.

Session and authentication handling depend on the binding you're using. If you're using basichttpbinding, for instance, the host basically acts like a web server and no persistant "sessions" are created; as a result each SOAP request you send must contain everything necessary for authentication on the host. However, there are some bindings available like WSHTTPBinding that allow for the creation of security and reliability sessions that persist after the initial authentication using a token.

Wrapping the message in SSL should prevent problems.